# How to fix non response mysql connection in PHP

Tags: php

I am trying to get a variable from a mySQL table into my PHP code. I am using a mysqli_query command. When I try to echo the result, it echos nothing, not even other echo statements.

I have ensured that the $conn is correct and working, and that the Sql query is correct by running it directly in PHPmyAdmin.

```
<?php
session_start(); 

include_once("includes/dbh.inc.php");

    $UID = $_POST['userIdVariable'];

    $UID = $_SESSION['u_uid'];

    $balance = "SELECT account_balance FROM `users` WHERE user_uid = \"$UID\"";//this line probably works

$result = mysqli_query($conn, $balance);

echo "$result";
```

When I run this code it would output nothing. The right side of the $balance line is a good sql query according to PHPmyadmin. The $UID variable is read in correctly.

Comment: `mysqli_query` returns true\false\object, not the results of the query

Comment: adding to @tim : you'll need [mysqli_fetch*](https://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli-result.fetch-assoc.php) to get the result in a way to work (display) with the result set. See https://www.php.net/manual/en/class.mysqli-result.php for the options you have

Answer (score 0):

You need to use mysqli_fetch function to get result columns out of $result object.

```
while ($data = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
    printf("%s \n", $data["account_balance"]);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

**Don't use quotation in a field name or table name inside the query.**

```
$balance = "SELECT account_balance FROM users WHERE user_uid = '$UID'";
```

Answer (score 0):

**please check your database connectivity.there could be something missing like database name.**

**and print your $UID. may be there is no id getting.**

**to print data use print_r();**

and try this:

```
session_start(); 
$servername = "localhost";
$username = "username";
$password = "password";
// Create connection
$conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password,"databasename");
     $UID=1;
     $balance = "SELECT account_balance FROM users WHERE user_uid =$UID"; 
    $result = mysqli_query($conn, $balance); 
    if (mysqli_num_rows($result)) { 
        while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) { 
            echo $row['account_balance'];
        } 
    }
```